# How to logout a user from a desktop session without terminating his processes via a command line?

Tags: ubuntu, terminal, logout, xfce

I am making MYSELF a restraint of sitting at the laptop by using crontab and time.conf for me not to be able to log into the system at specific hours.
Yet the options the internet provides is by using 'skill -KILL -u user' which terminates ALL the processes of the session. Yet I want to just be kicked out to the login window, because I don't want all my works to be lost.
In another words, I am looking for a terminal command that will "switch user", not "logout".
I am using the latest Xubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution:
$ dm-tool switch-to-greeter

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).